# Login form redirect not working

Tags: craft3, form, redirect

My login form  is not redirect like I want it to.

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
{{ csrfInput() }}
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="users/login">
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="profile">

<h3><label for="loginName">Username or email</label></h3>
<input id="loginName" type="text" name="loginName"
    value="{{ craft.app.user.rememberedUsername }}">

<h3><label for="password">Password</label></h3>
<input id="password" type="password" name="password">
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="rememberMe" value="1">
    Remember me
</label>

<input type="submit" value="Login">
```

Anybody know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All redirect parameters needs to be hashed in Craft 3. If not, they're completely ignored.

Try using:

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="{{ '/profile' | hash }}">
```

Or

```
{{ redirectInput('profile') }}
```

Comment: That would explain why every redirect variation I attempted failed.  This works perfectly, thank you.